# find adjacent blocks with same color

Tags: javascript, canvas

im making this "pop the balls" game and im having trouble on how to find the adjacent balls with the same color as the one we played. can anyone help me with that?

my javascript code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var width = 800;
            var height = 700;

            var COLS = 24;
            var ROWS = 6;
            var balls = [];
            var ballsCL = [
                {color:'rgb(255,0,0)', label:"r"},
                {color:'rgb(0,255,0)', label:"g"},
                {color:'rgb(0,0,255)', label:"b"},
                {color:'rgb(255,255,0)', label:"y"},
                {color:'rgb(255,0,255)', label: "cr"},
                {color:'rgb(0,255,255)', label: "lb"}
            ];

            var count = 0;

            var Ball = function(x, y, w) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.label = ballsCL[w].label;
                this.color = ballsCL[w].color;

                this.draw = function() {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

            var Player = function() {
                this.x = width/2;
                this.y = height-15/2;
                this.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
                this.angle = 0;

                this.draw = function() {
                    ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
                        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
                        ctx.lineTo(0,-70);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(0,-70);
                        ctx.lineTo(-10,-60);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(0,-70);
                        ctx.lineTo(10,-60);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }

            var player = new Player();

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

            var NewBall = function(x, y, w) {
                this.iniX = x;
                this.iniY = y;
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.color = ballsCL[w].color;
                this.label = ballsCL[w].label;
                this.angle = 0;
                this.v = 5;
                this.slide = false;
                this.w = w;
                this.d = 0;
                this.sticked = false;

                this.draw = function() {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                this.move = function() {
                    if(this.slide == true) {
                        this.x -= Math.sin(this.angle) * this.v;
                        this.y -= Math.cos(this.angle) * this.v;
                    }
                }
                this.stick = function() {
                    if(this.slide) {
                        for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
                            this.d = Math.round(Math.sqrt((this.y - balls[i].y)*(this.y - balls[i].y)+(this.x - balls[i].x)*(this.x - balls[i].x)));

                            if(this.d <= 25) {
                                this.v = 0;
                                this.y = balls[i].y+30;
                                if(this.x <= balls[i].x && this.x >= 30) {
                                    this.x = balls[i].x-30/2;
                                }
                                if(this.x >= balls[i].x) {
                                    this.x = balls[i].x+30/2;
                                }
                                this.slide = false;
                                this.sticked = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
                this.toArray = function() {
                    if(this.sticked) {
                        balls.push(new Ball(this.x, this.y, this.w));
                        this.sticked = false;
                        newBall = new NewBall(player.x, player.y, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0);
                    }
                }
                this.edges = function() {
                    if(this.x <= 37/2 || this.x >= width-37/2) {
                        this.angle = - this.angle;
                    }
                }
            }

            var newBall = new NewBall(player.x, player.y, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0);

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

            function pushBalls() {
                for(var i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
                    for(var j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
                        if(i % 2) {
                            balls.push(new Ball(25+j*32+30/2, 30+i*30, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0));
                        }
                        else {
                            balls.push(new Ball(25+j*32, 30+i*30, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            pushBalls();

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

            function addRow() {
                count++;

                if(count % 1000 === 0) {
                    for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
                        balls[i].y = balls[i].y+30;
                    }
                    if(balls[0].x === 25) {
                        for(var i=23; i>=0; i--) {
                            balls.unshift(new Ball(25+i*32+30/2, 30, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0));
                        }
                    }
                    else if(balls[0].x === 40){
                       for(var i=23; i>=0; i--) {
                            balls.unshift(new Ball(25+i*32, 30, Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0));
                        } 
                    }
                }

            }

            function init(){
              requestAnimationFrame(draw);
              canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
              canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseOver);
            }

            function mouseUp(e) {
                if(newBall.x == player.x && newBall.y == player.y) {
                    mouseX = e.clientX - (canvas.offsetLeft - window.pageXOffset);
                    mouseY = e.clientY - (canvas.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset);

                    newBall.angle = Math.atan2(newBall.x-mouseX, newBall.y-mouseY);
                    newBall.slide = true;
                }
            }
            function mouseOver(e) {
                mouseX = e.clientX - (canvas.offsetLeft - window.pageXOffset);
                mouseY = e.clientY - (canvas.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset);

                player.angle = -Math.atan2(player.x-mouseX, player.y-mouseY);
            }


            function draw() {

                ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,700);

                for(var i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
                    balls[i].draw();
                }

                player.draw();

                newBall.draw();
                newBall.move();
                newBall.edges();
                newBall.stick();
                newBall.toArray();

                addRow();

                requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            }

            init();
```

and the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eskimopest/ojb4cyqa/1/

Answer (score 1):

Give every ball object a row & column property and then check neighboring balls around this balls row & column. If the balls move, adjust their row & column.

For example, check these neighboring balls with these row,col:

```
[row-1,col], [row+1,col], [row,col-1], [row,col+1].
```

You can also check diagonal neighbors if desired:

```
[row-1,col-1], [row-1,col+1], [row+1,col-1], [row+1,col+1]
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer and i'm sorry, i know this maybe is to much to ask but can you guide me through the process? it's just that the way i did it, i dont know how to make this work.